# import_meta_graph fails with Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number)

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, tensorflow

### Context

I came across this problem while trying to solve another error. The first error (original problem) was that when I tried to restore a meta graph I would get `Cannot find KeyError: "The name 'multi_rnn_cell_6' refers to an Operation not in the graph."`. In trying to create the MVCE for that problem I found this error.

### Problem

A simple script which creates some ops, saves the meta graph and variables, and then tries to load the graph and variables fails.
The problem seems to be related to the format TF is using.

### MVCE

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import glob

class ImportIssue(object):
    def __init__(self,load=False,model_scope = 'model',checkpoint='checkpoint'):
        try:
            os.makedirs(checkpoint)
        except:
            pass

        save_file = os.path.join(checkpoint,'model')
        print("Save file: {}".format(save_file))

        graph = tf.Graph()
        with graph.as_default():
            if load:
                # load model if requested
                model_to_load = "{}.meta".format(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint))
                print("Loading model: {}".format(model_to_load))
                rest = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_to_load)
            else:
                # else create one
                with tf.variable_scope(model_scope):
                    inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,10,10),dtype=tf.float32)
                    cell = self._build_cell(10)
                    # this cell is failing to be fond
                    #print(cell.name)
                    rnn,state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell,inputs,dtype=tf.float32)
                    train_op = self._build_training_op(inputs,rnn)

            saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES), max_to_keep=1)
            with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
                if load:
                    rest.restore(sess, model_to_load)
                else:
                    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
                sess.run(train_op,feed_dict={inputs:np.random.normal(size=[3,10,10])})
                saver.save(sess, save_file)
                print("Saved model and graph")
                print("Files in checkpoint dir: {}".format(glob.glob("{}/*".format(checkpoint))))



    def _build_cell(self,size):
        with tf.variable_scope("decoder"):
            cells = []
            cells.append(tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(size,activation=tf.nn.tanh))
            for res_block_i in range(1):
                res_block = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(size, use_peepholes=True) for i in range(2)])
                res_block = tf.nn.rnn_cell.ResidualWrapper(res_block)
                res_block = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(res_block, input_keep_prob = 1.0,
                        output_keep_prob = 0.5, state_keep_prob = 0.5,
                        variational_recurrent = True, dtype=tf.float32)
                cells.append(res_block)
            cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells)
            return cell

    def _build_training_op(self,inputs,rnn):
        o = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(inputs - rnn))
        return o.minimize(loss)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ImportIssue()
    ImportIssue(load=True)
```

Prints

```
Saved model and graph
Files in checkpoint dir: ['checkpoint/model.data-00000-of-00001', 'checkpoint/model.meta', 'checkpoint/checkpoint', 'checkpoint/model.index']
Save file: checkpoint/model
Loading model: checkpoint/model.meta
```

The error is:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: Unable to open table file checkpoint/model.meta: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
```

### Versions

Python 3.6 Fedora 64bit Linux
TF 1.4

Answer (score 9):

Yep checkpoint has to be specified without the .data-00000-of-00001 that seems to be added to end of all checkpoints created in the V2 tf graph save methods.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check [issue 2676](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2676)
Also why not use the saver.restore functionality directly (will restore the whole checkpoint at once) instead of doing it through the metagraph?

Comment: In that issue the user has mis-specified a configuration file. In my MVCE I clearly create a new meta graph object and then immediately try to load it, so there should be no mis-specification, and the versions used to write and load the model should be identical.

Comment: Also, wrt using saver.restore, I am use that to restore variables once the graph is loaded into the default graph.

Comment: yes, but you can directly create a Saver object passing the constructor the list of variables you want to load `tf.train.Saver(var_names)` and then just run `saver.restore(session, path_to_checkpoint)` 
No need to go through a Meta file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes because `Saver.restore` is trying to restore from a meta file. That answers this problem, but unfortunately the code now works and the MVCE isn't reproducing the original bug I'm trying to create.